# What account does IIS Express run under?

Tags: iis, permissions, x509certificate, privileges, iis-express

I need to get my dev machine to read a certificate from the local machine store

to do this I need to run winhttpcertcfg.exe and specify the account I want to elevate

What would this account be for IIS express?

(For IIS it would be the IWAM_MachineName)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 43, accepted):

IIS Express runs as your user account. When installed, you should find an IISExpress folder in your My Documents folder.